# How do I open a chrome browser using ruby, cucumber, capybara and bddfire gem?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I am very new at BDD testing and I am trying to figure out how to open a chrome browser in a specific URL using these technologies. I already installed bddfire gem and already ran it.

Now I have a feature:

```
@openingChrome
Scenario: Opening Chrome on facebook page
Given I open chrome and write "url"
```

bddfir_steps.rb

```
Given(/^I open chrome and write "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
    $session.visit("https://www.facebook.com.br")
end
```

In the hooks file I wrote

```
Before do
  $session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium, browser: :chrome)
end
```

And in the env.rb file that came with bddfire gem there is this

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

So chrome is already added and I already installed chrome webdriver. Unfortunately this line of code is not working: $session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium, browser: :chrome)

it throws this error:  `The second parameter to Session::new should be a rack app if passed. (TypeError)`

does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Session#new takes the name of the driver and optionally a rack app instance to start. Since you don't seem to be starting an app and you're registering your driver with a name of :chrome you want

```
Before do
  $session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
end
```